# Curl command to test the API

Tags: api, rest, curl, command-line

I need to test an API of following spec

```
URL: http://myapp.com/api/upload/
Method: POST
Parameters: 
   image: (binary data of image)

returns
   a JSON Object
```

sample php implementation to test the api

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://myapp.com/api/upload/';

$fields = array('image'=>file_get_contents('profile-pic.jpg'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$json = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\n".$json."\n";

?>
```

I use RESTClient and Poster extensions to test other api, I'm not sure how to send binary data for a parameter named image with those tools.

How do I test the above api using Curl command?

No luck with this one

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "image=@test.jpg" "http://myapp.com/api/upload/"
```

`test.jpg` is in current directory. I can't change the 3rd party API, to be able to test with other encoding formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'image@test.jpg' 'http://myapp.com/api/upload'
```

It’s `image@`, not `image=@`.

This is assuming that the image data is urlencoded before sending, which is what I figure the PHP code does.

Answer (score 1):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with a hash array in PHP corresponds to the command line -F option. Thus, it should be something similar to:

```
curl -F image=@profile-pic.jpg http://myapp.com/api/upload/
```

If that isn't the exact thing, add '--trace-ascii dump.txt' to get a full trace logged and check that out closely to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the --trace-ascii I was not aware of that. +1