# Using PHP to Add Facebook Open Graph Read Action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to get Facebook to publish a read action using PHP. I've coded it totally wrong and need a little help:

```
<?php    
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>

<?php

curl -F 'access_token=MY ACCESS TOKEN' \
     -F 'article=echo 'echo curPageURL();' \
        'https://graph.facebook.com/me/news.reads'

?>
```

The second part is that bit I can't translate into PHP properly. I've no idea where to start as I'm a novice with PHP and only just learning the Open Graph API.

Comment: `curl -F 'access_token=MY ACCESS TOKEN' \...` is not a valid php code. PS: novices should start with basic things, not such complicated ones

Comment: If you continue using cURL and PHP, you may want to read ["PHP: cURL - Manual"](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and ["PHP: cURL Functions."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: I know it's not valid php code hence why I asked the question. Thanks creemama I've tried to read the manual already but struggled to find a way of incorporating curl -F into php

Comment: Perhaps searching Google for ["submitting form curl php"](https://www.google.com/search?q=submitting+form+curl+php) may help. For example, ["Submitting a form post with PHP and CURL"](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/") shows the use of `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. This Stack Overflow question, ["Curl command to test the API,"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683338/curl-command-to-test-the-api) shows a relationship between `curl -F` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the cURL functions in PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you used the Facebook PHP SDK https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/, it was developed by Facebook to provide access to their API and it manages the cURL connection for you.